# Duplicate and slide edge (rip from boundary)

Tags: modeling, edges

I have a simple plane.

I select one edge and I would like that edge to be duplicated and slid.

I cannot rip the edge <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> because it is on a boundary.

I could extrude out from the shape to leave the edge inside the shape then rip. This is a long way around, **is there a better solution?**

thank you

Starting object with edge selected.

[image]

*In C4D there is a clone edge tool and if used would give*

[image]

I cannot replicate in Blender

Comment: could you please show how your mesh is supposed to be after the operation, you only show before and in my opinion the arrows are not enough

Comment: @moonboots - thanks for looking. Example now posted which I should have done in the first place rather than trying to keep it too simple

Comment: ok I think it's clearer  ;)  I don't know how to do it though... If I had to do it I would extrude then bring back the 2 edges where there are supposed to be, but you loose the original edge position...

Comment: Yes that was the only solution I had was to extrude then rip. Or add an edge loop as far as possible, disolve the edges that are not needed and use the knife tool to clean up. The first option to extrude then clean up is the quickest. Thanks

Comment: why rip? just extrude, then move back where the edges are supposed to be

Comment: I was looking for the quickest and precise option and thought I had missed something and that rip could be used. With extrude (top view) I would be trying to put the extruded edge back to where the original was which is not precise. But you are right it is an option thanks

Comment: You could hang on to the position of the original edge by , (with snap set to Vertex & Active,) shift-D duplicating a vertex at one of its ends, leaving it in place. Then extrude, then snap the extrusion (with an appropriate vertex active) back to the loose vertex, before merging it away.

Comment: @RobinBetts thanks robin yes I could create a guide and snap to it. The best method for me is to knife cut, slide (gg e f) and pick up the correct edge if possible. If not then clean up with the knife/dissolve. The initial question was in case I missed the option of  something similar to clone, which is rip but unfortunately rip does not work on a boundary. thanks again

Comment: ..I think your way is the best.. I often find myself making temporary, disposable extrusions.. sometimes just to get some face-normals, which wouldn't otherwise exist, for other tools..

Comment: @barkest I will make an observation, your example creates a ** NGON **, which does not work very well in blender, I will also make a very timely comment, CAD4 is for engineering and architecture, and does not do the same things that blender and blender do not it does the same thing as cad, maybe you can program an addon for blender in python that does what you want, but still has the problem of engon, your request is too inefficient, there are better ways to achieve what you are looking for, assuming that what you want is simply a parallel cut to the edge that points

Comment: @BlenderBlackened thanks for the comment. Not sure where the ngon is? I was not comparing Blender to C4D only that the tool existed there and wondered if I had missed something in Blender that was similar. I have several ways to achieve what I am looking for but rather than stay inefficient I would rather ask, after I have tried everything of course. If one of the ways you are thinking of has not been mention, either by me or others I am happy to learn from you. Thanks again

Comment: I will give you an example of how I can solve it, it will surely give you an idea to achieve your goal

Comment: thank you I appreciate it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the edge on the border and add a loop cut there. Since usual *Loop Cut And Slide* tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) won't do in this case due to 5-pole, use *Offset Edge Slide* instead.

[image: nifty gif image]

This way will create triangle after cutting and sliding along edges which compose 5-pole, small  cleanup is required there to merge one vertex to another.

See *[Offset Edge Slide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop.html#offset-edge-slide)* in manual.

As mentioned in comments by @Leander, *Offset Edge Slide* indeed has options you can enable while executing it. Like *[Loop Cut and Slide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop.html#loop-cut)*, it provides:

- *Even* mode which matches the shape of the created edge loop to existing edge loop from one side;
- *Flipped* option which controls which edge loop will be taken into account by *Even* mode;
- *Clamp* which allows to toggle limiting to existing edge loops.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @barkest You can also press E, while sliding the vertices around to keep an even distance from their starting origin.

Comment: @Leander thank you

Comment: Wow.. all this time, I never knew it worked on boundaries!

Answer (score 2):

So, as you gave additional elements, it seems to me that there is no answer to your problem.

**Except:**

Extrude your edge then move the original + new edges to the position where they are supposed to be.

**My former answer:**

- You could create an edge loop
- then <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to slide
- then press <kbd>E</kbd> to slide parallel to the next edge
- then <kbd>F</kbd> to switch and make it parallel to the other edge

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should not have used a plane as you are correct. I really just want to to be able to 'clone' and slide the edge. I used a plane as a very poor example. I do not think what I want to do is possible

Answer (score 1):

It is not a complex problem, regarding blender, this would be the most efficient way to do it, with the minimum of clicks and time spent to achieve this result.

My figure is obviously not identical but it repeats the number of edges and faces vertices that your model has in order to create the example

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

***NOTE:***
*Another option would be a small script that generates this type of cuts as if it were a bevel, but it may take a little longer to do the Python script*

Comment: Thank you for your help - much appreciated

Comment: I will try to find another more efficient way, surely there is some faster way to achieve this

Comment: very kind of you thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try Inset Faces (with Boundary B). Before that you need to separate the certain faces from the object.
[image]