# Can I use something similar to "Slide Vertices" to create new vertices and edges?

Tags: mesh, vertices

I use `Slide Vertices` (hotkey `Shift-V`) to slide multiple vertices along a face. I also use the tool in edge mode to slide edges along a face. Does Blender have a tool that does the same function but leaves the original vertices/edges and also creates new vertices/edges that slide along existing faces?

Here is an example workflow to clarify what I mean:

- I select multiple vertices that make up an edge or edges (call these `original_verts`)
- Use some tool/shortcut that I hope exists in Blender
- Use mouse to slide the selected edges along adjacent faces
- Release mouse, where new vertices/edges will be created on where I released, but `original_verts` remain in their original positions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a related question: [Duplicate and slide edge (rip from boundary)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148788/duplicate-and-slide-edge-rip-from-boundary)

I don't think there is a way to do *exactly* what you want in vanilla blender. But there are a few things you can try depending on what you want to achieve exactly, and what kind of mesh you're working on.

1. Just for a quick reference, instead of sliding verts with <kbd>Shift-V</kbd>, you can do the same more quickly by just pressing <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> while your vertices or edges are selected.
2. The first thing that comes to mind is the [Offset Edge Slide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/offset_edge_slide.html) tool. Not to be confused with normal [Edge Slide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/edge_slide.html). All you have to do is select the vertices you want, and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. This will slide your new vertices where you want, but as a downside it will do so symmetrically. So you will have to clean up the side that you don't want by just dissolving.

Here's an example video:

---

[image: Offset Edge Slide]

3. Another option that could work how you describe is just a simple extrude. The key is to change the snapping options to `edge`, and when you are extruding hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hover over the desired edge. Once you've completed the extrusion, you will need to merge duplicate vertices by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> and selecting "By Distance" since this method will create duplicate geometry.

Example video:

---

[image: Extrude Video]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. After testing, using Offset Edge Slide is great if I want to have the new edges to both sides. As in my comment to coyohti, I find it best to first hide the faces that I don't want to get edited. The Extrude method doesn't work in my test when I have more complicated edges because the extrude command follows only one reference edge, and because of this, I got vertices that got created outside of existing edges.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this a variety of ways, depending on the mesh and your ultimate goal. These are methods I would try.

If you need a whole new edge loop you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, position the yellow loop, LMB, and then you have the option to slide the loop to a position you'd like. LMB again to set position or RMB to just set the loop at the median point.

You can also select a group of vertices or edges, RMB for a context-sensitive menu, and choose "Subdivide". You'll need to position the result verts/edges but that can be done quickly by double-tapping the <kbd>G</kbd> key to slide once they are selected.

Comment: Thanks. Edge Loop may be the best way for my case, especially if I want the edges to go on one side. Hiding the faces that I don't want to get edited, followed by adding an edge loop, is the quickest and cleanest way to do what I wanted. Cultmethod's suggestion in using Offset Edge Slide is good if I want new edges to go on both sides of the original edges.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you may want to use *Rip Fill* : Select your edge, put your cursor on the side where you want the duplication to happen and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>G</kbd> to slide the new edge along the other edges. It would be better it automatically slide. Also, it looks like it works only on one side in 2.9 for the moment (?).

Another option is to create a new edge with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> then make it slide with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> then press <kbd>E</kbd> to make it parallel to the next edge, then <kbd>F</kbd> to make it parallel to the opposite edge.

Comment: Rip Fill is indeed what I need, and you are right that it can only work on one side for 2.9 (bug?)

Comment: Yes, maybe it needs to be reported to Blender developers, if it's not fixed in next Blender version